# Open a new Google Chrome tab and get the source

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Google Chrome extension and I'd like to know how to open a new tab (ok, this is simple:
`chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL(mypage)}, function(tab) { /* ... */ });`
) and retrieve the source code of that page.

I know that I can use AJAX to get the source, but the problem is that the web page contains some Javascript code that edits the page, and I need the edited page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please use upvote to thank and do not thank in question.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example? Would you be able to host it? I copied the example on the bottom verbatim, but I still could not get it working...

Answer (score 11):

To serialize the full, live HTML document, use the following code:

```js
// @author Rob W <http://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w>
// Demo: var serialized_html = DOMtoString(document);

function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    var html = '',
        node = document_root.firstChild;
    while (node) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                html += node.outerHTML;
            break;
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                html += node.nodeValue;
            break;
            case Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
                html += '<![CDATA[' + node.nodeValue + ']]>';
            break;
            case Node.COMMENT_NODE:
                html += '<!--' + node.nodeValue + '-->';
            break;
            case Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE:
                // (X)HTML documents are identified by public identifiers
                html += "<!DOCTYPE "
                     + node.name
                     + (node.publicId ? ' PUBLIC "' + node.publicId + '"' : '')
                     + (!node.publicId && node.systemId ? ' SYSTEM' : '') 
                     + (node.systemId ? ' "' + node.systemId + '"' : '')
                     + '>\n';
            break;
        }
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
    return html;
}
```

Now, in a Chrome extension, you have to add some events to the extension page such as a background page or popup page:

```js
/**
 * Get the HTML source for the main frame of a given tab.
 *
 * @param {integer} tabId - ID of tab.
 * @param {function} callback - Called with the tab's source upon completion.
 */
function getSourceFromTab(tabId, callback) {
    // Capture the page when it has fully loaded.
    // When we know the tab, execute the content script
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onUpdated);
    chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(onRemoved);
    function onUpdated(updatedTabId, details) {
        if (details.status == 'complete') {
            removeListeners();
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
                file: 'get_source.js'
            }, function(results) {
                // TODO: Detect injection error using chrome.runtime.lastError

                var source = results[0];
                done(source);
            });
        }
    }
    function removeListeners() {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(onUpdated);
        chrome.tabs.onRemoved.removeListener(onRemoved);
    }

    function onRemoved() {
        removeListeners();
        callback(''); // Tab closed, no response.
    }
}
```

The above function returns the source code of the main frame in a tab. If you want to get the source of a child frame, call [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) with a `frameId` parameter.

The next snippet shows an example of how your extension could use the function. Paste the snippet in the [background page's console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension/10258029#10258029), or declare a [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), put the snippet in the `onClicked` listener and click on the extension button.

```js
var mypage = 'https://example.com';
var callback = function(html_string) {
    console.log('HTML string, from extension: ', html_string);
};
chrome.tabs.create({
    url: mypage
}, function(tab) {
    getSourceFromTab(tab.id, callback);
});
```

The referenced **`get_source.js`** contains the following code:

```js
function DOMtoString(document_root) {
    ... see top of the answer...
}
// The value of the last expression of the content script is passed
// to the chrome.tabs.executeScript callback
DOMtoString(document);
```

Don't forget to add the appropriate [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), so that you can read DOM from the page. In the above example, you have to add `"https://example.com/*"` to the "permissions" section of manifest.json.

### Related documentation

- [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) <sup>MDN</sup>
- [`DocumentType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentType) (`document.doctype`, `<!DOCTYPE ... >`) <sup>MDN</sup>
- [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [Match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [Manifest > permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>
- [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) <sup>Google Chrome Extension docs</sup>

Comment: I know this is very old, but, it's just what I'm looking for. Unfortunately... it never calls the 'demo' function! Where/how do we do that?

Comment: @phil `demo` isn't called anywhere. I've edited the answer to add more detail.

Comment: @RobW It would be nice to have a step by step tutorial of this. Sort of like what google does: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/development-basics/