# Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension. I need to analyse from the HTML source of the current page. I found here all kinds of solutions with background pages and content scripts but none helped me. here is what I have so far:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "bmarkred.ico",
    "popup": "Test.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "page": "backgroundPage.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

`background.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {action: "getSource"}, function(source) {
                alert(source);
            });
        });
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

`content.js`

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == "getSource") {
        callback(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
    }
});
```

The alert always alerts undefined. even if i change in the content.js file the callback function to:

```
callback('hello');
```

still the same result. What am I doing wrong? maybe I'm going at this the wrong way. What I really need is this: When the user opens the extension popup (and only then), I need HTML of the current page so I can analyse it.

Comment: A problem is that the code in your background page is run immediately (before the content scripts are injected). A very similar/duplicate question has been asked before; Have a look at the answer at [Open a new Google Chrome tab and get the source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10162291/938089?open-a-new-google-chrome-tab-and-get-the-source).

Comment: Thanks for your reply rob. i copied the code segments in your attached link but it still doesn't work. The problem is that my extension is a popup and i need to get the HTML only when the user opens my extension. for example, if the current tab is facebook.com then only when i open my extension, i will retrieve the html source to my js file (not the content script or the background page).

Comment: Update your question with your current code. The code has to contain comments which highlight the problem.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Inject a script into the page you want to get the source from and message it back to the popup....

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "name": "Get pages source",
    "version": "1.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "Get active tabs or element on that pages source from a popup",

    "action": {
        "default_title": "Get pages source",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "scripting",
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

**popup.html**

```js
function onWindowLoad() {
    var message = document.querySelector('#message');

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }).then(function (tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        var activeTabId = activeTab.id;

        return chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: activeTabId },
            // injectImmediately: true,  // uncomment this to make it execute straight away, other wise it will wait for document_idle
            func: DOMtoString,
            // args: ['body']  // you can use this to target what element to get the html for
        });

    }).then(function (results) {
        message.innerText = results[0].result;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + error.message;
    });
}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;

function DOMtoString(selector) {
    if (selector) {
        selector = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (!selector) return "ERROR: querySelector failed to find node"
    } else {
        selector = document.documentElement;
    }
    return selector.outerHTML;
}
```

Comment: @Gil Tankus So sorry for my first post, didn't pay enough attention to the comments (again) and ended up just regurgitating what Rob W said.  The new post should have what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was really helpful, my problem is that the on onMessage happens asynchronous. in my popup, i have all sorts of other stuff that relay on the source HTML. how can i save the source in a global var and only then continue with the page onload function?

Comment: I don't think you can.  Your either going to have to put it in the callbacks code or in a function and call that in the callback...if only JS had a `goto` command aye? ;P

Comment: Why not just something like document.documentElement.outerHTML instead of the DOMtoString function?

Comment: @djfm That would be fine pretty much all of the time.  Its just that from what I could tell Rob W's function is more complete...returns the doctype for instance that your solution doesn't, yours is only getting the html part.

Comment: I want to use document.getElementByTagName in popup.js where document is document object of the current tab. I couldn't do it. I changed `DOMtoString(document)` to `document` and tried to use it as `request.source.getElementByTagName` but things didn't work that well. Any comment?

Comment: This answer works by *re-generating* the page source from the DOM (which could be altered by other scripts at runtime), it doesn't return the raw HTML response from the server.

Comment: The must bizare thing it's i wanted to have another ID then message like #getsource but the document.querySelector('#gethtml') do nothing. i just put gethtml.innerText without document.querySelector() Can you explain that?

Comment: So was it meant to be getsource or gethtml?...maybe that was it.
Theres a thing where you can access an element by just using its id in js....Ive never seen anyone use it.  I wouldnt, could see it being a big source of confusion, especially as its not known by everyone. Heres a simple example....  http://jsbin.com/jedotoxuqa/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Can someone please tell how two parse that message.innerText so that i can do some calculation with the table values returned from a custom application page

Comment: @Share_Improve  [DOM Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) is good for that.

Comment: how can I `console.log` the `message.innerText` when updated, I'm familiar with `"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"], "persistent": false },`.. When I don't declare any background in *manifest* the *generated background page* doesn't appears, so I can't see the `console` or maybe it doesn't log. I tried editing `popup.js` the line after `message.innerText = request.source;`. 


**How can I solve this?**

Comment: Could someone update this to work with manifest v3 please? I have tried changing chrome.tabs.executeScript to chrome.scripting.executeScript and adding scripting to permissions, but there must be more. Thank you.

Comment: chrome.runtime.sendMessage needs an extension id as the first parameter

Comment: Bye bye manifest V2 :(

Comment: @PAEz it would be nice if this could be updated to "manifest_version": 3,

Comment: @samjco Merry Christmas, sorry your present is so late.  I havent done Chrome in over a year or more and had no knowledge of manifest 3, but this is working and Im pretty sure I covered everything.  I removed the old crawl code coz I think most people would prefer it this way.  Any problems just say and for a little while at least Im willing to fix any problems, answer any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
        if (request.action == "getSource") {
            this.pageSource = request.source;
            var title = this.pageSource.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1];
            alert(title)
        }
    });

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            tabs[0].id,
            { code: 'var s = document.documentElement.outerHTML; chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "getSource", source: s});' }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried this method (and submit the app to Webstore) before? It's almost like a hack of using content_scripts without using it.