# Building a Firefox add on

Tags: firefox-addon

after I managed to create an add on for Chrome browser (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686561/chrome-addon-with-my-server-interaction),
my next target is to do the same for Firefox.

I see this is harder to do or there arent many good tutorials for begginers.
What Im asking is good step by step tutorials in order to understand the workflow for FF.
Thank you again for reading me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/builder). Here the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/), and you can also download it from [Github](http://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk).

I would say that the [Getting Started](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html#getting-started) section of Add-on SDK docs is a good place to start your reading.

You can also join the IRC channel #jetpack on irc.mozilla.org and ask help directly to the SDK team, if you have any doubt!