# Google Chrome Extensions: Get Current Page HTML (incl. Ajax or updated HTML)

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome extension, I need to be able to get the current page HTML, including any updated Ajax HTML (unlike the browser's View Source command, which doesn't update it).

Is there a way to get it as a string in my Extension?

Suppose my extension is a right-click context menu called "View Actual HTML Source" which should print the current HTML to the console, or maybe count the number of certain tags there. I wasn't able to find an easy answer to this.

Comment: Any other detailed explanations other than the answer below, which didn't really help much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the exact solution here, and this gave me the Page Source HTML:

[Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension)

The solution is to inject the HTML into the Popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current state of the DOM as HTML programmatically using `document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Or just use Developer Tools

Comment: No, that did not work for me. When I put this in my Context Menu Handler, I get this HTML no matter what: "<head></head><body><script src="background.js"></script></body> (size 65). This is not the HTML of any page I'm viewing.

Comment: That is a different issue. You are running it on the background page. Use `chrome.runtime.executeScript` or communicate with a content script to run it on the page.

Comment: You mean chrome.tabs.executeScript (not runtime)? Some details or examples of how to use this would be appreciated.