# Using a Chrome extension, how to get page source and save to a local file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome extensions, and don't need a lot from an extension, so I haven't studied JS or the HTML5 Chrome API in great detail (however, I do know HTML). Other pages in Stackoverflow were not quite what I was looking for.

Basically, I am writing a program that will take HTML page source data and parse certain information out of it for use with another program. What I need to be able to do is use a Chrome extension to get the source of a web page, then save it to a local HTML file for the program to use.

I'm using most of the extension source code from this thread: [Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension)

This works very well, except I need the source to go to a local file and not in the popup. In the popup, I'm going to add in a message like "File saved" along with a button to open the external program (if that's even possible). Any help or a step in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need the page's source, are are you looking for information in the live page (e.g. the target of a link with label "Click here")? And please do take the time to learn a bit about [Chrome's extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), because it helps you with comprehending existing answers. Do some research, and edit your question with information about what you have got so far and where you're stuck. I'll happily help, but only if you have demonstrated that you've put in some efforts in solving the problem yourself.

Comment: Turns out I can't use the page source for this program anyways, need to use an export file that the website will create. Thanks.