# How to get value of below c1x.cid, c1x.productID via jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser, browser-console

Hi I am new in jquery and javascript. Please help me to extract date from below code / function.

Below is the script section:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
  var c1x = {};
  c1x.cid = "63401";
  c1x.pageType = "PDP";
  c1x.productID =  "120367970";
  c1x.tileCount = 6;
  c1x.async = true;
```

or from below script tag present in the page source code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">        
  var m_id = 453;
    </script>        

    <script type="text/javascript">
  var l_id = 63401;
    </script>
```

I am trying to make chrome extention to extract productid and cid of every page. 
For reference below is the 
[Main web page link](http://www.shopclues.com/moto-x-play-with-turbo-charger-black-16-gb-120367970.html)

Comment: What is the end result you want and could you please add the code you've tried so far? You should just be able to access them via `window.c1x.cid` etc.

Comment: I want to alert or popup the CID and PID value from the HTML page. Currently looking for the exact code to extract the data from page so the I can implement . I am sorry till now I have not created any code.. But tried document.getElementsByTagName("script") and alert(document.getElementsByClassName('pID')[0].innerHTML);

Comment: Ok, that's definitely not going to work as you're trying to select a javascript object like a HTML element. Try not to use `alert` in the final code but this should work for now: `alert(window.c1x.cid);`. I'd also strongly recommend looking at some intro to web development tutorials as otherwise you're going to run into a lot of issues.

Comment: @Joe Please help me to extract data from 

 <script type="text/javascript">        
  var m_id = 453;
    </script>

Comment: The exact same way in my comment above, `window.m_id`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Joe
Will also check web development tutorials R&D.

Comment: Plugins cannot talk to web page javascript directly. They need to talk via [messages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). You need to inject some javascript on page load to scrap the id from the web page and can extract it via messaging. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696154/4073386)

Comment: Thanks @SiddhantPatra