# Grab current URL from within extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For my Google Chrome extension, I need to grab the current URL. I know that, in regular JavaScript, I can just use this to get the link and host:

```
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
var url = window.location.href;
```

But how can I do that within an extension? I actually got it to work by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension) as an example, but it seems a bit overkill for what I want to do. Is there a better way to get the current URL, maybe without injecting a script into the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `chrome.tabs.query()` to get the current URL into a variable inside your extension code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function(tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Remember: the part of your code that'll use the `url` variable should be inside the (anonymous) callback function above, not elsewhere. Otherwise, you'll get an `undefined` value, as Chrome extension code is executed asynchronously.

Comment: Awesome! One question, is there a way to pull the hostname from the tab, too? I got around it by grabbing the url and using 'new URL()' to turn it into an actual url that comes with a hostname, but maybe there is an easier option.

Comment: Using `URL()` is now the standard way to deal with URLs across most modern browsers (not just for Chrome extensions) so in your case `var hostname = new URL(tabs[0].url).hostname;` instead should give you the hostname only.