# Google Chrome Extension Get Details of the Page in Active Tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Google Chrome extension that collects details of the page loaded in active tab.
I am getting the page title and URL correctly, but the page HTML source is not loading.
This is the code I am using to get title and URL:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  u = tab.url;
  t = tab.title;
  document.write("Title: "+t+"<br>URL: "+u);
});
```

How can I get the HTML source of the tab page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: No sir, please help me on this issue.

Comment: That answer is the only thing I can think of based on the way your question is phrased. You should provide more details or rephrase the question so we can understand the problem.

Comment: I am trying to create a Chrome extension that collects the HTML Source of a particular site and post it to my PHP script.  I am getingt the Page URL and Page Title using tab.url and tab.title respectively.  But the page HTML Source is not available this way.  How can I get the HTML Source of a page?  Highly appreciate your support.

Comment: The answer I've linked contains an exact solution of this problem.