# Get page's server response before client side manipulation

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to retrieve a `script` tag from a page using `chrome extension`. If i open `view page source` i can see the script tag but if i view it using devtools its not there. The client side removes that script. I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension) the response is same as manipulated by the browser. How can i access the script tag before its removed?

Comment: Chrome extensions can't do that but it's possible to read the scripts even **after** they were deleted, see the answer below. In Firefox there is onbeforescriptexecute event.

Answer (score 0):

Use [chrome.debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API to read all running scripts even if their tags are removed.

manifest.json:

```js
"permissions": ["debugger", "activeTab"]
```

browser_action's popup.js or background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, async ([tab]) => {
  const pageScripts = await getTabScripts(tab.id);
  console.log(pageScripts);
});
```

```js
function getTabScripts(tabId) {
  const results = [];
  let resolveMain;
  let timer;
  function onEvent(src, method, info) {
    if (method === 'Debugger.scriptParsed' && info.executionContextId === 1) {
      results.push(getSource(info));
    }
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(doResolve, 100);
  }
  function getSource(info) {
    const {scriptId, url} = info;
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId}, 'Debugger.getScriptSource', {scriptId},
        e => resolve({code: e.scriptSource, url, info})));
  }
  function doResolve() {
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.removeListener(onEvent);
    chrome.debugger.detach({tabId});
    resolveMain(Promise.all(results));
  }
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolveMain = resolve;
    chrome.debugger.attach({tabId}, '1.3', () => {
      chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener(onEvent);
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand({tabId}, 'Debugger.enable');
    });
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, it'll temporarily show a panel above the tab about it being debugged but you can reduce the timeout `100` to something like `20` if all results are still getting reported.

Comment: Thanks but the scripts i got using your answer are either `copyright` or anonymous function with 2 or 3 line arbitrary code where url is either empty or `chrome-error://chromewebdata/`.

Comment: None of them relate to the actual page i'm debugging

Comment: I can't help further without seeing the actual site.

Comment: One last thing: try removing `&& info.executionContextId === 1`  to see all scripts.

Comment: I got the page's script but it was without the code which is being removed. Anyways thank you for your help.