# How can I get the HTML source code of the website the user is currently on using the tabId and the chrome extension API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

This is my `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "Description",
  "version":"1.0",
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Here is my `background.js`:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (typeof changeInfo.url !== "undefined" && changeInfo.url.startsWith("chrome://newtab/") === false){
    alert(changeInfo.url);
    //somehow get the HTML of the page given tabId and store as string
}
});
```

It will be greatly appreciated if someone can help me out here. As I specified before, I need the exact HTML of the page as the user sees it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the sites you want to be able to read (or all sites `"*://*/*"`) to `permissions` in manifest.json, then use chrome.tabs.executeScript to extract its HTML as a string.

- DOM elements or class objects like `Map` can't be extracted. Only **JSON-compatible types** such as strings, numbers, boolean, `null` and array/objects of these types can be extracted.
- The popup is a separate window so it has its own **separate devtools**: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu to see console.log messages.

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (info.url && !info.url.startsWith('chrome')) {
    const html = await getHtml(tabId);
    console.log(html);
  }
});

function getHtml(tabId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: 'document.documentElement.outerHTML',
    }, results =>
      chrome.runtime.lastError
        ? reject(new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message))
        : resolve(results[0]));
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but `document.documentElement.outerHTML` is returning something starting with `<html style="font-size: 10px;font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" lang="en" dark="true"><script type="text/javascript" class="__REQUESTLY__SCRIPT">(function(namespace) {
  window[namespace] = window[namespace] || {};
  window[namespace].responseRules = {};
`
instead of the normally `doctype html`. Why would this be happening?

Comment: That's the correct result because doctype isn't part of DOM. You can add it explicitly if you need it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696154).