# Is there a chrome API for viewing contents of open sites?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im looking for a way to read the source only of open tabs on my browser, specifically music.apple.com. What chrome api should I use for this? Ive been searching around their docs but couldn't find anything that looks like what I need.

Comment: It's probably related to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Modify_a_web_page

Comment: There's no such API. You'll have to use a *content script*, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11696154).

Comment: Thanks for helping! Ill look into content scripts @wOxxOm