# Get innerHTML via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to fiddle around with Chrome Extension development and thought I would make a simple v3 Extension where if the icon is clicked, the content of a particular html element will be logged to the console. However, when I click the icon, I got `null`.

What I have so far:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Test Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Some test extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Log the content of #someElement to the console"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(execScript);

async function execScript() {

  const tabId = await getTabId();
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tabId},
    files: ['mycode.js']
  })
}

async function getTabId() {
  const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  return (tabs.length > 0) ? tabs[0].id : null;
}
```

**mycode.js**

```
(function() {
  console.log('yes'); // this one works
  console.log(document.querySelector("#someElement").innerHTML); // this doesn't and returns null
})();
```

And the html page that I tried to click the extension icon on has the following content:

```
<body>
  <!-- some html content -->
  <div id="someElement">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum text</p>
  </div>
  <!-- some html content -->
</body>
```

Comment: Nothing suspicious so you need to debug it. The common reasons: a) clicking too soon before the element was added by the page, b) not running in the correct iframe, c) a filter in console toolbar. Click the icon once so mycode gets injected, open devtools for the web page, open mycode.js in Sources panel, set a breakpoint inside mycode.js, click the icon again so the breakpoint triggers, then inspect the *actual* state of DOM at the moment this code runs.

Comment: @wOxxOm It was `b)` haha Thanks for pointing that out man.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the source HTML of the current page from chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684454/getting-the-source-html-of-the-current-page-from-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was simply because the html element was inside an iframe. Thanks to @wOxxOm for pointing that out in the comments.

I fixed it by changing `mycode.js` to:

```
(function() {
  const iframeElement = document.querySelector("#iframeId");
  const iframeCont = iframeElement.contentWindow || iframeElement.contentDocument;
  const iframeDoc = iframeContent.document ? iframeContent.document : iframeContent;
  console.log(iframeDoc.querySelector('#someElement').innerHTML);
})();
```