# Extracting subtitle from a teachable/hotmart video

Tags: video, extract, subtitle

After may hours, I found a way how to extract the subtitle text from a teachable/hotmart video in a half-automatic way. Is there any way to automate the process?

The problem for a more sophisticated solution is that the video data is referenced inside an `<iframe>`, so accessing its contents from outside is prevented by CORS rules. A further problem is that the video containing the subtitle cannot be loaded with any normal user interface provided.

My **process** is the following steps:

1. Open the video e.g. in Chrome or Edge
2. Stop the video and move to the place where you want to start subtitle extraction (the first subtitle to be recorded should not yet be shown)
3. Open the developer panel with context menu "Inspect"
4. In the "Elements" tab, follow down the elements tree for those elements, which highlight the video area, until you find an "iframe" node with "src" parameter value starting with "https://player.hotmart.com"
5. Under that "iframe" node, open nodes #document/`<html>/<head>`
6. Under that `<head>`, replace the empty script node (`<script></script>`) with the code below, using e.g. "Edit as HTML" context menu
7. Clear the console tab
8. Let the video run the whole part that you want to extract the subtitle from
9. Save the console log as a text file
10. Remove the unnecessary file and rownumber using a text editor in the saved console log

Code to be replaced with:

```
<script>
var txt="";
(function checkSend() {
    var pres = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
    if (pres.length>0) {
        var t=pres[0].innerHTML;
        if (t!=txt) {
            txt=t;
            window.console.log(t);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(checkSend, 1000);
})();
</script>
```

Comment: **(1)** You can't ask for software recommendations here. Just use Google search for such needs. **(2)** What happens if you open the _"https://player.hotmart.com"_ link in a new tab? Does it show a full page player? If yes, what happens if you copy the source code into a text file on your computer then run that text file as an HTML page? Eg: Does the player still work? If yes, what happens if you do your **step 6** on the text file and then reload that as HTML page? Is your problem solved? If not then please show a real testable link...

Comment: player.hotmart.com - This page could not be found.
And I cannot see any advantage in the process you describe. It is only more work.

Comment: And I cannot share the page I have tested with, because it is password protected, and I do not share my credentials.

Comment: **(1)** _"player.hotmart.com - This page could not be found"_ Really? Just follow your own instructions: _"...Find an `"iframe"` node with `"src"` parameter value **starting with** `"https://player.hotmart.com"`"_ and it will work (you never told us a known working link, so you must add that missing part yourself when you test).

Comment: **(2)**  _"I cannot see any advantage in the process you describe"_ Your problem is with **CORS** and with using `<iframe>`... the possible solution (if you care to test) is to run your own customized HTML/JS version of that same iframe content. Forget the `<iframe>`,  **stop trying to edit an i-frame's source code** (because CORS issues) and alternatively just open the i-frame's `src` URL in a new tab then copy that source code into your own (text) file that you run as your own customized HTML and with your JS code added to it. We cannot test anything, you must confirm if player still works.

Comment: With the problem of iframe I just mean that I cannot use any access from outside to the contents of the iframe, which could enable a more sophisticated approach to the whole thing. However, the procedure that I describe, works, because I use the developer pane to access and modify the code within iframe. Copying the src part of the iframe to another browser tab works. Naturally that could enable a more sophisticated solution, but as such, it still would include that manual part described above, i.e. even more manual work.

Comment: The automation part comes later (by using PHP, which does not care about CORS and "just works"). First you must confirm/test manually that a modified HTML (to include your JS code) still works when running that edited HTML file from your own location (for security, some sites block such outside requests if they are not originating from their own servers). **To test**: _"Copying the src part of the iframe to another browser tab works."_ so now use `ctrl+u` on that tab to see the source code (it should start with `<html>` and include `<head>` section etc). Copy the whole source code...

Comment: ...And paste it into a text file (then save it as as `test.html`), now when you open your own `test.html` in the browser does the video player still work (no "blocked" or similar errors in console)? If yes, then put your custom JS code into the empty `<script>` area and test again. If that works great... because now we can move on to automating (PHP will get source as text, modify text add JS code, then give back to your page a new iframe now with modified JS code. Because proved it still works, the new iframe should also work and you see subtitles being extracted).

Comment: PS: **(1)** My _"put your custom JS code into the empty `<script>` area and test again"_ means put JS code in your HTML file (not using Developer Tools) then re-save and test. **(2)** When moving onto automating, you must use your computer's localhost server address to run the PHP code from your hard drive or else you will need to put the HTML file on your website online (most servers can run PHP code).

Comment: When I copy the source code that is loaded when entering that address in parameter src as URL, and save the source as html, and then try to open that file with the same browser, the displayed page remains empty. In the console, there is nothing, either. So it seems that the video is somehow not called (no initialization?). Additionally, I forgot to say before that everything that I have mentioned to work, I tested only in the same browser where I already had logged in in that video provider. So, there may be some cookies or similar that are needed if the work is translated to PHP.

Comment: The problem could be that the address (src value) has some additional parameters which are crypted, and assumedly have some crucial information like credentials and time. This crypted URL parameter is naturally not sent to the provider when called from test.html

Comment: More tests: the src-string (player.hotmart.com/....) works also in a browser where login has not been made. The file test.html with the URL parameters from that string does not work (with or without login), but there comes different error messages (it seems that you do not have an internet connection... or we had a mistake around here, try playing this video again or visit our Help Center). It could be difficult to implement a PHP based solution. What about e.g. a Chrome add-in, which makes that replacement automatically that I describe in the beginning?

Comment: **(1)** If seeing `file://` in the address bar then some things might not work (_eg:_ Fetch API). Just to be sure... Try instead to run the files from your localhost server. The address of the _test.html_ file must show in the bar as starting with: `http //127.0.0.1/...` (or even `http //localhost/...`) when opened in the browser. On Windows you can install XAMPP if needed, on MacOS you should already have localhost. **(2)** Yes, a custom Chrome Extension would work if its code is just to detect an element and get its innerHTML. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70505002/2057709).

Comment: I put test.html in my own homepage. And it worked, also without the extra URL parameter, i.e. just as test.html. But after a while it stopped working. I assume that the contents are time-restricted through some crypted parameters.
The link for the Crome Extension is good. Thanks. Maybe, I will try to implement like that. It seems that there the access to iframe contents is allowed.

Comment: A Chrome extension works, when I use "content_scripts" in manifest.json with "matches" set to https://player.hotmart.com/*, "all_frames" to true, and "js" to a javascript file name having that script above. So I think this request is now solved.

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. Out of interest why do you want their subtitles so badly (_eg:_ they are already visible in the hotmart player anyways, so why store extra copies of exact same data)?

Comment: To be able to translate to other languages.
By the way, you helped me to find the solution, so how can I mark that here?